# ObjectMapper to serialize a class with Enumeration member

Tags: scala, jackson, objectmapper

I have an Enumeration in Scala

```
object Status extends Enumeration {
  type Status = Value
  val Success = Value
  val Error = Value
}
```

This is used in the below -

```
case class Response(
    status: Status,
    errorMessage: String
)
```

I want to store `Response` in a file. So, I am using Jackson object mapper (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`    )  to serialize it.

```
writeOutputToFile(filePath: Path , objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response))
```

However, object mapper writes an empty json to the file. I know object mapper requires a getter method to serialize. Is that why this is failing? Would I need a custom object mapper?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270621/using-jackson-to-de-serialize-a-scala-case-class answer your question?

Comment: Just a part of it. My main concern was about the Enumeration class. ObjectMapper prints it as `{"status":{"scala$Enumeration$Val$$i":0},"message":null}`

Comment: Jackson is Java library and it doesn't understand how Scala defines things. Which is why wrapper might help. Though the easy way is wrapper and no-`Enumeration`

Comment: You might prefer a sealed trait with case objects

Answer (score 0):

You can define generic serializer and deserializer for all enums and then for each of them register corresponding pairs of instances:

```
class EnumSerializer[T <: scala.Enumeration](e: T) extends JsonSerializer[T#Value] {
  override def serialize(x: T#Value, jg: JsonGenerator, spro: SerializerProvider): Unit = 
    jg.writeString(x.toString)
}

class EnumDeserializer[T <: scala.Enumeration](e: T) extends JsonDeserializer[T#Value] {
  private[this] val ec = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, T#Value]

  override def deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): T#Value = Try {
    val s = jp.getValueAsString
    var x = ec.get(s)
    if (x eq null) {
      x = e.values.iterator.find(_.toString == s).get
      ec.put(s, x)
    }
    x
  }.getOrElse(ctxt.handleUnexpectedToken(classOf[T#Value], jp).asInstanceOf[T#Value])
}

val objectMapper: ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper = {
  val jsonFactory = new JsonFactoryBuilder()
    .configure(...)
    .build()
  new ObjectMapper(jsonFactory) with ScalaObjectMapper {
    registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    registerModule(new SimpleModule()
      .addSerializer(classOf[Status], new EnumSerializer(Status))
      .addDeserializer(classOf[Status] new EnumDeserializer(Status))
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

The proposed solution is much safe and more efficient in runtime than just using of `Status.withName(s)` for each deserialization.

It will work even for the dynamic definition of enum values, like:

```
object Status extends Enumeration {
  type Status = Value
  val Success = Value
  val Error = Value

  def extra(name: String): Status = Value(nextId, name)
}

Status.extra("Unknown")
```

Full sources are [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/commit/367091a57e4d18ec4ba3f735ee554c233d8f5e48).