# Error creating RDD in Apache Spark from JSON Array

Tags: apache-spark

people.json

```
[{"name":"Michael"},
{"name":"Andy", "age":30},
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}]
```

I am trying to load the above JSON into an RDD using the below code

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

var jsonFile = new java.io.File("people.json")

var mapper = new _root_.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper()

var people = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, classOf[java.util.ArrayList[Person]])

val peopleRdd = sc.parallelize(people.toArray).map(i => i.asInstanceOf[Person])

peopleRdd.collect()
```

I get the following error when I call collect() method

```
15/02/19 21:51:51 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to $line17.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Person
        at $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        at $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/02/19 21:51:51 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to $line17.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Person
        at $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        at $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/02/19 21:51:51 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to $line17.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Person
        at $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        at $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/02/19 21:51:51 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to $line17.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Person
        $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        $line30.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/02/19 21:51:51 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to $iwC$$iwC$Person
        $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I am not able to get past this error.
Please help me to understand the error and steps to get past it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Jackson deserialized your json not into an Array of Person objects, but into an Array of LinkedHashMap objects.

So this is a problem with Jackson deserializing Scala case classes. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966743/small-example-of-jackson-scala-module) answer I gather you need to register DefaultScalaModule.

I am missing some Jackson classes right now, so I cannot try that line, but the rest of your code works, if people is an ArrayList of Person objects.

Answer (score 0):

The input must have a valid data in each line, so it can be split among many workers. Change your people.json file to:

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
```