# How to convert arry:string to specific model in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I want to convert `array: String` to `Seq[Message]`...

Case class:

```
case class Message(name: String, sex: String)
```

Source:

```
[
    { "name": "Bean",
      "sex": "F"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "sex": "M"
    }
]
```

Destination

```
Seq[Person]
```

How to convert?? code...

Comment: read the docs here: http://json4s.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of decoders/deserialisers to decode string into `case class`. There are tons of decoders in scala. One of my favourite is [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) as it is functional and also works pretty well with scalajs.

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._

case class Message(name: String, sex: String)

val encoded =
  """
    |[
    |    { "name": "Bean",
    |      "sex": "F"
    |    },
    |    {
    |      "name": "John",
    |      "sex": "M"
    |    }
    |]
  """.stripMargin

val decoded: Either[Error, List[Message]] = decode[List[Message]](encoded)

decoded match {
  case Right(e) => println("success: " + e)
  case Left(l) => println("failure: "+ l)
}
```

**output:**

```
success: List(Message(Bean,F), Message(John,M))
```

If you looking for plain simple compatible with java, take a look at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

Also see: [Scala deserialize JSON to Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130653/432903)